# Assigning to 'id<Delegate>' from incompatible type 'ViewController *const_strong'

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

Throughout my app, I'm getting semantic issue warnings when I set `ViewController.delegate = self`.  I have searched and found similar posts but none were able to solve my problem.

ViewController.m:

```
GameAddViewController *gameAddViewContoller = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
gameAddViewContoller.delegate=self;
```

I get the error message when setting `.delegate=self`.

GameAddViewController.h:

```
@protocol GameAddViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)gameAddViewControllerDidCancel:(GameAddViewController *)controller;
- (void)gameAddViewController:(GameAddViewController *)controller didAddGame:(Game *) game;

@end

@interface GameAddViewController : UITableViewController <GameAddViewControllerDelegate>
{
sqlite3         *pitchcountDB;
NSString        *dbPath;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <GameAddViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
...
@end
```

ViewController.h:

```
#import "GameAddViewController.h"

@class ViewController;
@protocol ViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)ViewControllerDidCancel:(ViewController *)controller;

@end
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ViewControllerDelegate>
-(void) checkAndCreateFile;
@end
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to resolve the warning messages?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

At this line :

```
gameAddViewContoller.delegate=self;
```

Notice that self is of type `ViewController` which does NOT conform to the `GameAddViewController` protocol.

Comment: What do I need to do to fix this.  Is there something I need to change in the GameAddViewController protocol?

Comment: Well, it depends on who you want to be your delegate. Who is implementing the GameAddViewController protocol

Comment: GameAddViewController is the child of ViewController and I am implementing the gameAddViewControllerDidCancel method in ViewController.  The error message is from the prepareForSegue method in ViewController when I set gameAddViewContoller.delegate=self.

Comment: So do as @borrrden suggested. Conform the `ViewController` to the `GameAddViewControllerDelegate`  delegate.

Comment: OK, so I finally got it.  I added this to my header file //#import "GameAddViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <GameAddViewControllerDelegate>
@end//

Comment: Or, this might help other people with similar problems:   @interface myViewControllerName : UIViewController<MCSessionDelegate>

Comment: How did this get accepted and 72 votes? This answer just rewords XCode's warning and provides no solution.

Answer (score 66):

For me what ended up happening is that I wasn't adding the delegate to the @interface on my header file

For example

```
@interface TheNameOfYourClass : UIViewController <TheDelegatorClassDelegate>

@end
```

Answer (score 14):

You are putting the < GameAddViewControllerDelegate > in the wrong place.  It doesn't go on GameAddViewController, it goes on ViewController.

Answer (score 4):

This might help other people who are adding Multipeer Connectivity straight to a ViewController. At the top of myViewControllerName.h add '<MCSessionDelegate>':

```
@interface myViewControllerName : UIViewController<MCSessionDelegate>
```

Answer (score 1):

also, if you define your delegate on xx.m, but you use it in other class. you may get this problem. so, just put protocol define on xx.h, when it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a hybrid project, the protocol in Swift and the assignment in Objective-C:

Swift declaration:

```
protocol BackgroundTasking {
    func beginTask(withName: String, expirationHandler handler: (()->Void)?)
    func endTask(withName: String)
}
```

Objective-C assignment:

```
@property (nonatomic) id<BackgroundTasking> backgroundTasker;

_backgroundTasker = [[BackgroundTasker alloc] init]; // WARNING
```

**Assigning to '__strong id' from incompatible type 'BackgroundTasker *'**

You need to declare the class (to remove this warning) and the functions (to make them accessible) as **@objc** for them to be correctly bridged.

Correct Swift declaration:

```
@objc protocol BackgroundTasking {
    @objc func beginTask(withName: String, expirationHandler handler: (()->Void)?)
    @objc func endTask(withName: String)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On hybrid projects you should add your delegates on .h file instead of .m file